# Newsstand download several issues with NKAssetDownload in one time

Tags: ios, objective-c, newsstand-kit

I try to make a newsstand app, and i have a question. I make my app according [this tutorial](http://www.viggiosoft.com/blog/blog/2011/10/17/ios-newsstand-tutorial/). It's so awesom tutorial, and app work fine, but i want users to have opportunity to download several issues at the same time. Example from [tutorial](http://www.viggiosoft.com/blog/blog/2011/10/17/ios-newsstand-tutorial/) can't do that, but [THIS](http://ios-blog.co.uk/tutorials/how-to-make-a-magazine-app-in-ios-part-ii/) tutorial's example do. That is part of code, which init downloading:

```
 NSString *downloadURL = [issueToDownload downloadURL];
    NSURLRequest *downloadRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:downloadURL]];
    NKIssue *nkIssue = [issueToDownload newsstandIssue];
    NKAssetDownload *assetDownload = [nkIssue addAssetWithRequest:downloadRequest];
    [assetDownload downloadWithDelegate:issueToDownload];
```

And this code is the same as in [this](http://www.viggiosoft.com/blog/blog/2011/10/17/ios-newsstand-tutorial/) tutorial. So, can someone please tell me what i mess? Or, maybe, i watch to the wrong side? Thanks a lot.